# Advice on dynamically adding data to MVC View and passing to Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm developing an MVC 5 web application. Within one of the Razor Views I need to implement functionality which I've never done before. Below is a quick mock up of what I intend my Razor View to look like.

[image]

Let me explain how I'd like this to work.

1. The user selects a consultant and days from the two drop down menus, then clicks the Add button. This will then make the data appear in the table below without performing a postback, however, this action will not persist the data to the database.
2. The user can add as many records as they wish, while also deleting and editing.
3. The user then enters data into the three remaining textboxes, Client, Telephone and Email.
4. The user then clicks the Add Entry button. Once this is done, the data on the screen is passed to an action within my controller by a ViewModel and the data is then inserted into two tables.

   TblProposal(**proposalID (PK)**, clientName, telephone, email)
   TblProposalConsultant(proposalConsultantID, **proposalID (FK)**, consultantID, days)

The reason why I can't insert the data into the **TblProposalConsultant** table when the user selects each consultant and their days, is because, this table has a Primary Key/ Foreign Key relationship with **TblProposal** which records the Client, Telephone and Email. Therefore, the primary key in the **TblProposal** table is needed before the Consultant and their days can be recorded in the **TblProposalConsultant** table.

Is this approach even possible? If so, what would be the best approach to add the consultants and their days to the table without any postbacks, but then to also have this data sent back to my action in the controller?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks all.

Comment: It's possible and easy. You can store consultant and their days in a json using hidden field,localStorage, data- attribute. Then simply add this as a row in a table and finally post it to your action. If the user removes the consultant from the table you just remove it from your json.

Comment: @MatijaGrcic Thanks for you reply. Do you know of any links or tutorials explaining this in more details?

Comment: Maybe this http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/02/01/working-with-html5.aspx can give you an idea and help you get started.